# How do I keep my form from clearing the 'Name' input field after submitting it and from asking it to be filled again?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

After displaying a confirmation message(div) my contact page wipes the name input field (but not the e-mail field) and promptly gives the 'please fill out' warning. How would I resolve this?

Here is my js and HTML code

**JS**

```js
function validateInfo() {
  var x = document.forms['contactMe']['yourName'].value;
  var y = document.forms['contactMe']['yourEmail'].value;
  if (x !== '' && y !== '') {
    document.getElementById('infoValid').innerHTML =
      document.getElementById('fullName').value +
      ' thank you, I will be reaching out to you soon!';
    document.getElementById('fullName').value = '';
  } else if (x == '' && y !== '') {
    document.getElementById('error-name').innerHTML =
      ' Please Enter Your Name* ';
    return false;
  } else if (x !== '' && y == '') {
    document.getElementById('error-email').innerHTML =
      ' Please Enter Your E-mail *';
    return false;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<form id="contactMe" action="" method="post">
  <fieldset id="contactInfo">
    <legend>Contact Information</legend>
    <div class="infoRow">
      <label for="fullName">Name or Honorific and Last Name*</label>
      <input
        name="yourName"
        id="fullName"
        type="text"
        style="font-size: 25px"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div class="infoRow">
      <label for="fullNumber">Phone Number</label>
      <input
        name="yourNumber"
        id="fullNumber"
        type="text"
        style="font-size: 25px"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="infoRow">
      <label for="fullEmail">E-mail*</label><br />
      <input
        name="yourEmail"
        id="fullEmail"
        type="text"
        style="font-size: 25px"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div class="infoRow">
      <label for="fullNote">Notes or Comments</label>
      <textarea
        rows="3"
        cols="60"
        name="yourNote"
        placeholder=""
        style="font-size: 25px"
      ></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateInfo()" /> *By clicking
    the Submit Button, you will be sending your provided information out to
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use input type button to stop the page reload

```
input type="button"
```

Comment: That worked to stop the "Please fill out" but it still clears the name input filed but not the e-mail input field.

Comment: Delete method="post" and try it again

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateInfo()">
```